# Razor page independently post form to each controller

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

In my asp.net razor project, I have page containing multiple forms. But if I post to table update, the main info form data change would be lost. How can I submit table without changing my other form data?

(I guess I can try to make the page using js+ajax without razor binding, but I will first try the razor solution)

```
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.data.Test.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.data.Test[i])</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" class="container" asp-page-handler="delete">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@i" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

//the main user info form
<form method="post">

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="data.UserName" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="data.UserName" class="form-control" readonly />
    <span asp-validation-for="data.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

 ... other inputs.

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
```

Comment: There's not a pure Razor solution for this. If you think about web pages, if you have a normal form post, the original web page is going to be lost when any of the other forms submit. Razor doesn't change that, it's just a templating language for generating HTML. So your idea of using JavaScript is what you need to do.

Comment: Thats right, this isnt a Razor problem and cannot be solved with pure Html. You could use JavaScript to serialize the data in the other forms and pass that back in the current form via a hidden input

Comment: Can you post your model pls?  And pls post the top of the view too.  You have hided the most important parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ajax and use `event.preventDefault();` which can prevent reloading the page.Here is a demo:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">

   <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="data.UserName" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="data.UserName" class="form-control" readonly />
    <span asp-validation-for="data.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

 ... other inputs.

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Save()" />
</div>
</form>
```

js:

```
function Save()
        {
            event.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
                url: '/.../...',
            }).done(function (result) {
                
            });

        }
```